# Check if Facebook/Twitter account has changed in iOS Settings

Tags: ios, acaccountstore

I have an application that needs to check for Facebook and Twitter account stored in iOS Settings. I can fetch both successfully. My question is how can I check if the user has deleted the account and inserted a new one in iOS Settings. If the user goes back to the app, it needs to check the new account stored by the user.

This is the app Im trying to pattern my app into.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for "ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification".
eg.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(refreshAccounts:) name:ACAccountStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)refreshAccounts:(NSNotification *)note
{
    NSLog(@"Refreshing Accounts");
    //whatever code you want 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Can you post whole code. I tried adding the NSNotification but it doesn't seem to trigger when I delete accounts in Settings > FB/Twitter.

Comment: Updated the code. When your app is backgrounded to allow the Settings to be changed by the user, modifying access to a given social account will automatically trigger this event and execute any code prior to resuming your app.

Comment: I tried this but is not working for me. Just put an NSLog inside refreshAccounts but is not being triggered. Could I be missing something?

Comment: Make sure this colon is here... @selector(refreshAccounts:)

Comment: It still not working. Put exactly the same code you provided, went to the viewController in my app. Went to settings > Twitter > Deleted Account. Went back to app, no log message.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, then. Works for me. I have both in main view controller, fwiw. I'm assuming you are able to see other NSLog entries in your console.

Comment: Also, I assumed you have Social.framework and Accounts.framework added to project and headers imported?

Comment: I finally got it to work. I just needed to pass the ACAccountStore as the object parameter for the NSNotificationCenter. Thanks for helping @gro

Answer (score 0):

Take twitter account for example.

How about add the following function as below? 
You can fetch account again after finding account info changed.

```
- (void)checkTwitterAccountUpdate
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
    ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts lastObject];
    NSString *localTwitterName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"kTwitterKey"];
    if([localTwitterName length] > 0)
    {
        if(![twitterAccount.username isEqualToString:localTwitterName])
        {
            NSLog(@"Account did change");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if(granted) {
                NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts lastObject];
                NSLog(@"%@", twitterAccount.username);
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:twitterAccount.username forKey:@"kTwitterKey"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
        }];
    }

}
```

in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self checkTwitterAccountUpdate];
}
```

Comment: I would want to only do a requestAccessToAccountsWithType once... Maybe store the ACAccount after that. But I cannot seem to store ACAccount on standardUserDefaults.

Comment: How about set the username to nsuserdefault? Just updated the code.